# git rebase : how git restores hashes of copied commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have this scenario.
I had a `develop` branch which goes like this:

```
c1->c2->c3-----develop
```

then I checkout my `feature` branch from `develop` and made some commits while other people continued to commit in `develop` branch.

```
c1->c2->c3->c7->c8->c9----develop
         |
         |--c4->c5->c6----feature
```

After a while, instead of doing `rebase`, I did `git merge develop` in my `feature` branch. So it became like this:

```
c1->c2->c3->c7->c8->c9----develop
         |           \
        c4->c5->c6->c10----feature
```

where `c10` is merged commit.
Then I continued to do some commits in my feature branch.

```
c1->c2->c3->c7->c8->c9----develop
         |           \
        c4->c5->c6->c10->c11->c12----feature
```

Then, I wanted that only commits made by me should come at top of my branch. So , I did `interactive rebase` in my `feature` branch.

```
git rebase -i c3
```

and reordered commits. Now since I reordered, I got new commit hashes.

```
c1->c2->c3->c7'->c8'->c9'->c4'->c5'->c6'->c10'->c11'->c12'
```

Now my commits are on top of my branch and I squashed my commits(`c4'..c12'`).

```
c1->c2->c3->c7->c8->c9 ------develop
         |
         c7'->c8'->c9'->c13' -----feature (c13 is squashed)
```

Now when I do `git rebase develop`, as per my understanding my branch should be on top of `develop` branch and should looks like this(`c7",c8",c9",c13"` are new hashes):

```
c1->c2->c3->c7->c8->c9->c7"->c8"->c9"->c13"-----feature
```

However, `git` restores original hashes and `feature` branch looks like this(`c7,c8,c9` restored):

```
c1->c2->c3->c7->c8->c9->c13"-----feature
```

How does `git` identify copied hashes and restored them while doing rebasing ?

Comment: The short answer is "it doesn't" - but due to patch ID computations, it's possible that if the original commits already exist on the branch onto which you're rebasing, those will remain, and the new copies will be dropped.